# JBoss: @Resource not injected when classloader isolation enabled

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, resources, classloader

JBoss 4.2.3, an application deployed as a ear. Works. Then I enable classloader isolation by adding a `loader-repository` tag into `jboss-app.xml`. In multiple beans @Resource TimerService stops being injected and the code throws `NullPointerException`.

What could possibly be the reason of such behavior? I have no clue.

Thanks,
Artem B

Comment: what version of JBoss is this?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't have an answer but thanks to you I found the solution. I had this same problem occur in 5.1.0.GA. In my SLSB containing :

```
@PersistenceContext
EntityManager entityManager;

@Resource
TimerService timerService;
```

my entityManager would be injected just fine but timerService was yielding an NPE.
Once I commented out the `<loader-repository>...</loader-repository>` element in my jboss-app.xml voila, timerService was valid. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: indeed it was, but alas that seems to be akin to having your cake and getting to eat it too